# GCM for sending message to Topics

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) for the sole and singular purpose of sending messages to Topics. I am building an android app. I do have an app-engine endpoint server, fyi. I am wondering: what parts of the [Set up a Client App on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) process do I not need to implement?

Here is what I already included

- google-services.json
- compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0"
- the manifest edit portion (copy and pasted block pretty much)

But do I need to, for instance, obtain a InstanceID? What else do I need or not need? Ideally if someone has an example that exclusively uses "Topic Messaging" that would be great. But short of that, I can carry on with some pointers.

Do I need GcmListenerService, InstanceIDListenerService, **and** RegistrationIntentService?

Answer (score 0):

Sending topic messages with GCM is very similar to sending regular messages with GCM. The only differences are that the client must subscribe to the topic, and the sender must send to the topic.

To you questions about do you need GcmListenerService, InstanceIdListenerService and RegistrationIntentService... Yes.

Please have a look at [this quickstart](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm) which demonstrates GCM using topic and non-topic messages.

Also note that you should not be using:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0
```

please use:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0
```